# Match all (+) symbols between strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to catch this on Sublime Text.

**Have this:**

```
-webkit-calc(50%+4px/2+32px-32px*23%)
```

Want to catch all the + and - symbols inside calc so I can add a space between them...

**Like this**:

```
-webkit-calc(50% + 4px/2 + 32px - 32px*23%)
```

I have this already but caches all content inside calc(***) but just want all the + and -

```
(?<=calc\()(.+)(?=\))
```

Hope you can help me on this one guys,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `(?<=calc\()(.+)(?=\))` does not work because it only grabs what is in-between `calc(` and the last `)` on the line. You need to match `+` or `-` only inside those delimiters, and that is where `\G` operator comes in.

If there are no nested parentheses, you can use

```
(?:calc\(|(?!^)\G)[^)+-]*\K[-+]
```

Replace with  `$0` . For more safety, add a word boundary before `calc`: `\bcalc`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xH9pL1/1)

[image]
            V

[image]

The pattern matches:

- `(?:calc\(|(?!^)\G)` - matches `calc(` (matched with `calc\(` or `\bcalc\(`) or the end of the previous successful match (with `(?!^)\G`)
- `[^)+-]*` - 0+ characters other than `)`, `+` and `-`
- `\K` - omits the characters matched so far
- `[-+]` - match either `-` or `+`

If you want to only add spaces where they are missing, you could just match all spaces around the operators and replace them with single spaces:

```
(?:calc\(|(?!^)\G)[^)+-]*?\K\s*([-+])\s*
                             ^^^    ^^^^
```

And replace with  `$1` . This will turn `-webkit-calc(50%+ 4px/2 +32px   -   32px*23%)` to `-webkit-calc(50% + 4px/2 + 32px - 32px*23%)`.

Comment: Just to precise: `\K` is supported by Boost library used in SublimeText S&R.

Comment: You are the best! You just gave me a direct perfect answer and gave me a solution to something that you knew it would happen to me after with the solution to more spaces. **THANKS REALLY!**

Comment: You are most welcome, and thank you for cheerful tone.